# Windows registry APIs return ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT during pre-shutdown processing

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, registry

I'm doing pre-shutdown processing in my local service. For that I need to write some values into the local system registry (nothing big.) I call registry APIs from the SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN notification on Windows 7 and it works most times, except some time I start getting ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT returned from all registry APIs.

Any idea why I'm getting this error and what could be a workaround to save my data?

Comment: What registry key are you writing to? Also, wouldn't it make more sense to do this in `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN`?

Comment: Because SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN is not supported on Windows XP. I write into HKLM\Software\Company\Product

Comment: I think you're going to have to use conditional logic for the platform you're running on.  The HKLM tree gets locked at some point during shutdown on Vista and above.  That's one of the reasons for the SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN notification.

Comment: OK. Thanks, guys. I guess there's no way around it.